# Unix Timestamp in kdb/q

Tags: timestamp, kdb, q-lang

Is there a built-in way of getting the Unix timestamp in kdb/q?

Something like

```
`float$.z.p
```

would be ideal; otherwise I'll have to resort to a more laborious implementation where I count the seconds from Jan 1 1970.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
q)`long$.z.p
458558447196132000
q)`long$1970.01.01D00:00
-946684800000000000
```

So you can get nanos from 2000.01.01. From there it's a simple calculation to convert to and from a 2000.01.01-based epoch vs 1970.01.01 based epoch.

Comment: Awesome! thank you. For completeness, unix timestamp in kdb is 

    q)floor((`long$.z.p)-`long$1970.01.01D00:00)%1e9

Comment: @nightTrevors Note that there should be a backtick prior to the word `long`. This backtick is hidden due to the comment format.