# How do I convert a unix timestamp in int to a `timestamp in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm receiving unix msec timestamps of the form 1673240400000.

How do I convert these to native KDB timestamps?

I've tried various versions of

```
"P"$ string (1673240400000 % 1000)
```

But none of these seem to work. I was sure there was a built-in for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unix Timestamp in kdb/q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719209/unix-timestamp-in-kdb-q)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to account for the different epochs.

- Unix 1970
- kdb 2000

Also multiply by 1 million to get nanoseconds

```
q)epochOffset:`long$1970.01.01D0
q)epochOffset
-946684800000000000
q)`timestamp$epochOffset+1673240400000*1000000
2023.01.09D05:00:00.000000000
```

Comment: You could avoid explicit conversions using date-math: `1970.01.01+0D00:00:00.001*1673240400000 1673240400001`